# Show that $E(X)^2 \le E(X^{2/3})E(X^{4/3})$

Tags: probability-theory

Show that $E(X)^2 \le E(X^{2/3})\cdot E(X^{4/3})$

$X$ is a nonnegative r.v. I know the easiest way to prove this is using Cauchy-Schwarz, but I'm not sure how to get around squaring the probabilities in the expectation formula.

Comment: Though, if I let $X=0,1$ with prob. $1/2$ each, then $E[X]=E[X^2]=E[X^4]=1/2$ but $1/4>1/6\cdot 1/6$, contradicting your claim.

Comment: "squaring the probabilities in the expectation formula" What are you alluding to? One squares no probability when using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (which is indeed the shortest approach).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality states that $E(YZ)^2\leqslant E(Y^2)E(Z^2)$ for every random variables $Y$ and $Z$. Use this with $Y=X^{1/3}$ and $Z=X^{2/3}$.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I missed that derivation of the C-S inequality.